# Get/set user property on data lake blob in azure data factory

Tags: azure-data-factory

I'm looking for a way to access user properties on blobs in my data lake as part of an ADFv2 pipeline.  For example, say I have a blob trigger associated with my ADLSv2 linked service, and I want to get the value of a user property on the blob that triggered my pipeline called "dataVersion".

I imagined that I could use a Web activity, and build the URL using an expression that references the linked ADLSv2 service and the blob that triggered the pipeline to call the ADLS REST API to get the properties, but I'm struggling to find comprehensive documentation on what can be done with 'dynamic content'.

Other ideas for how you might access blob properties, or alternative ways to pass metadata along from pipeline to pipeline, would be welcome.

Answer (score 0):

1.If you want to get the properties in the blob file, you could use [Look Up Activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-lookup-activity). It can retrieve a dataset from any of the Azure Data Factory-supported data sources.

> Lookup activity reads and returns the content of a configuration file
>   or table. It also returns the result of executing a query or stored
>   procedure. The output from Lookup activity can be used in a subsequent
>   copy or transformation activity if it's a singleton value. The output
>   can be used in a ForEach activity if it's an array of attributes.

So you could pass the value of the desired property to subsequent activity with the expression `@{activity('MyLookupActivity').output.firstRow.TableName}`

2.If you want to get the metadata properties of blob itself,please use [GetMetadata activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-get-metadata-activity). The value could be targeted by the expression ,such as `@{activity('MyGetMetadataActivity').output.itemName}`

Comment: #2 is what I am after - a "user property" on a blob.  Two issues with your suggestion: 1 - the Get Metadata activity won't let me choose a dataset coming from Azure Data Lake Storage Gen 2, which is where my blobs are, and 2 -the documentation for the Get Metadata activity lists a specific set of metadata attributes it can retrieve ("metadata options" here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-get-metadata-activity).  This would be awesome if it worked, and would just leave me to figure out out to _set_ a user property.

Comment: @Brandon hi,any further progress?

Comment: I’m probably going to end up writing an azure function for this

Comment: @Brandon Great,then could you mark this answer to end this case.Thanks a lot.Will help you if you crash into issues in Azure Function.